# Error al enviar imágenes redimensionadas a base de datos usando imagecreatefromjpeg($ruta);

Tags: php, gd

Tengo un problema al cargar las imágenes de mi proyecto de inmobiliaria. Cuando las cargo al formulario y le doy subir imágenes me esta generando el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error:

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng() in C:\xampp3\htdocs\portalhome\admin\propiedades\up_principal.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp3\htdocs\portalhome\admin\propiedades\up_principal.php on line 25
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con la solución o decir que otra alternativa puedo usar para esta función?

Este es mi código:

```php
<?php
include '../conexion/conexion.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $id = htmlentities($_POST['id']);
    $cont=0;
    foreach ($_FILES['ruta']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
        $ruta = $_FILES['ruta']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $imagen = $_FILES['ruta']['name'][$key];
        
        $ancho = 500;
        $alto= 400;
        $info = pathinfo($imagen);
        $tamano = getimagesize($ruta);
        $width= $tamano[0];
        $height = $tamano[1];

        if ($info['extension'] == 'jpg' || $info['extension'] == 'JPG' ) {
            $imagen_original = imagecreatefromjpeg($ruta);
            $nueva = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho,$alto);
            imagecopyresampled($nueva, $imagen_original, 0,0,0,0, $ancho,$alto,$width,$height);
            $cont++;
            $ran = rand(000,999);
            $renombrar = $id.$ran.$cont;
            $copia = "inmuebles/".$renombrar.".jpg";
            imagejpeg($nueva,$copia);
        }elseif ($info['extension'] == 'png' || $info['extension'] == 'PNG' ) {
            $imagen_original = imagecreatefrompng($ruta);
            $nueva = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho,$alto);
            imagecopyresampled($nueva, $imagen_original, 0,0,0,0, $ancho,$alto,$width,$height);
            $cont++;
            $ran = rand(000,999);
            $renombrar = $id.$ran.$cont;
            $copia = "inmuebles/".$renombrar.".png";
            imagepng($nueva,$copia);
        }else {
            header('location:../extend/alerta.php?msj=Solo se admiten los formatos de imágen jpg y png&c=prop&p=img&t=error&id='.$id.'');
            exit;
        }

        $ins = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO imagenes VALUES(?,?,?) ");
        $ins->bind_param("iss",$id_img, $id, $copia);
        $id_img = '';
        $ins->execute();
    }// termina foreach

    if ($ins) {
        header('location:../extend/alerta.php?msj=Sus imágenes han sido cargadas con exito!&c=prop&p=img&t=success&id='.$id.'');
    }else {
        header('location:../extend/alerta.php?msj=Sus imágenes no pudieron ser cargadas&c=prop&p=img&t=error&id='.$id.'');
    }

    $ins->close();
    $con->close();
} else {
    header('location:../extend/alerta.php?msj=Utiliza el formulario&c=prop&p=img&t=error&id='.$id.'');
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes instalada la extensión php-gd para la manipulación de imágenes?

Comment: no tengo instalada esa extensión pero necesitaria instalarla tambien el el servidor del hosting y como lo haria

Comment: Sí, la necesitas porque esa extensión te permite el uso de esas funciones. Y depende del servidor y de lo que estés usando para programar, es decir: LInux, Windows... ¿qué usas?

Comment: mi hosting e Linux y mi pc es windows

Comment: uso Visual estudio code

Comment: Si es en windows, debes verificar en tu server de desarrollo en el archivo `php.ini` que la parte `;extension=php-gd.dll` esté desbloqueada y en tu server de producción debes hacer: `sudo apt install php-gd` y luego `sudo systemctl reload apache2` y ya deberías poder usar todo sin problemas.